# How to generate default values for a data class / POJO (in Kotlin/Java)?

Tags: java, kotlin

Remark: I ask it in Kotlin, but it applies to Java too.

For example, I have a POJO / data class:

```
data class Example(
    val someInt: Int,
    val someString: String,
    val someObject: Any,
    ... say it has 10 fields ...
)
```

I need to pass it to some code in my tests, and that particular code only cares about the `someString` field. Therefore, I hope I do not need to care about those other fields and just fill them with garbage (possibly just things like 0 and ""). Also, I do not want to use default values for the constructor, because for normal business code that field should be required, and it is only in test code that I want to fill dummy value.

Thus, I wonder how to generate default values for a data class / POJO (in Kotlin/Java)?

My naive thoughts: Use reflection and call the constructor. But I hope there already exist a library, or there is a simpler solution. Thanks!

**EDIT**

About why I need this: In the old days when using Java POJO, I can solve this problem by making the `Example` class like

```
class Example {
  int someInt;
  String someString;
  ...
}
```

Then I use it like

```
new Example()
  .setSomeInt(42)
  .setSomeString("hello")
  // I do not care about all other fields in this specific test case, so I just leave them null
```

But in kotlin, the idiomatic approach is to define the `data class` as the code example at the beginning of this question. Then, we see that (1) fields are final (2) not nullable. Then the old approach cannot work.

Comment: I usually have a factory method with default arguments in test, and construct the object using these values.

Comment: @sidgate Sounds great, but I just want to avoid duplicate code

Comment: Where would the duplication be exactly? You need to write the mapping between constructor arguments of `Example` and the default values you want in tests. This single shared function in the tests defines this mapping once. Or do you mean you would like to map all constructor argument strings of all types to empty strings, and all ints to 0 etc?

Comment: Yes I want to map all String type to "", all int to 0 etc

Comment: What's wrong with having a `val testExample = Example(1,2,3)` in your test source? or having a provider via Dependency Injection that is different for tests?

Comment: No offence, but if you take testing seriously, you need to create objects with the constructor you are going to use in the real application. You say it yourself: _...I hope I do not need to care about those other fields..._.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini question edited, thanks

Comment: @lukas.j question edited, thanks

Comment: why pass complete object to function under test when only few fields are required?

Comment: @sidgate For example, `class Book {String name; String subtitle; String isbn; ...}`, and method `insertBook`. I only test whether the book `name` is inserted correctly. Another example, if each function only inputs the exact fields it needs, I will have to create a lot of new classes. A third example: service A relies on (mocked) service B's `fetchBook()` method. The `Book` has 10 fields, and service A only cares about several fields in it. (I know my tests are not ideal, but really have no time to write finer tests currently)

Comment: Although your edit makes sense, you're fighting the language. What you're trying to do at this layer of your application makes no sense. If `normal business code that field should be required`, then in your test you want to either provide dummy values, mocks, or simply provide them because if production code cares, then the point of your test is to ensure this contract is not broken... You're essentially saying I need A, because production needs A, but in my tests I don't care about A. Then what exactly are you testing here?

Comment: Now, you show a java example where your constructor values, due to Java's nature, accept null values (though you should at least use the `@Nullable` annotation). Yet you say in prod null is not valid... so does production crash? The equivalent in Kotlin for a Java class like `class X(String nn)` is not `data class X(val nn: String)`, it would be `data class X(val nn: String?)`. In java, fields are nullable, so respect that in Kotlin and you can have the same behavior as Java.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I agree with you (and other people with similar opinions), and I will refactor the tests later. Thank you!

Comment: to answer your original question of whether there is any option, or to use reflection, or something else: I would still suggest go with simple factory method in test codebase that can be reused, easy to understand, and pass different field values for different scenarios

Answer (score 3):

You just have to initialize the data objects with some defaults in the setup code of your tests. One wonders why their values would not matter. Maybe this in itself is an indication that the code is not designed well.

If some fields truly don't matter for the test, just pass `null` or 0 or "" (of whatever simple default is applicable).

To avoid duplication you can set up a method for this that you use throughout your test.

Comment: thanks, I see that option

Answer (score 1):

As you mention yourself reflection would be a solution. Here is a solution quickly put together to give you a rough idea:

```
data class Example(
  val someInt: Int,
  val someString: String,
  val someObject: Any,
  val someList: MutableList<Any>
)

fun initializeDataClass(cls: Class<*>): Any {
  val constructor = cls.constructors[0]
  val arguments = mutableListOf<Any>()
  for (type in constructor.parameterTypes) {
    arguments.add(
      when (type) {
        Boolean::class.java      -> false
        Char::class.java         -> ' '
        Byte::class.java         -> 0
        Short::class.java        -> 0
        Int::class.java          -> 0
        Long::class.java         -> 0
        Float::class.java        -> 0.0
        Double::class.java       -> 0.0
        String::class.java       -> ""
        Array::class.java        -> arrayOf<Any>()
        BooleanArray::class.java -> arrayOf<Boolean>()
        CharArray::class.java    -> arrayOf<Char>()
        ByteArray::class.java    -> arrayOf<Byte>()
        ShortArray::class.java   -> arrayOf<Short>()
        IntArray::class.java     -> arrayOf<Int>()
        LongArray::class.java    -> arrayOf<Long>()
        FloatArray::class.java   -> arrayOf<Float>()
        DoubleArray::class.java  -> arrayOf<Double>()
        List::class.java         -> listOf<Any>()
        Map::class.java          -> mapOf<Any, Any>()
        Set::class.java          -> setOf<Any>()
        else                     -> Any()
      }
    )
  }
  return constructor.newInstance(*arguments.toTypedArray())
}

val example = (initializeDataClass(Example::class.java) as Example)
  .copy(someString = "abc", someList = mutableListOf(1, 2))
```

The last line contains three steps:

- creating the instance (with initializeDataClass)
- casting it to Example
- create a copy and set the desired fields to values which matter for the test

Answer (score 1):

One great way to generate data for classes in unit tests is by using the [kotlinfixture](https://github.com/appmattus/kotlinfixture) library.

It can generate random data for all fields in a model, including all subclasses. Example of how kotlinFixture would solve the question:

```kotlin
val fixture = kotlinFixture()
val example = fixture<Example> {
    property(Example::someString) { "mySpecificValue" }
}
```

Here `example` will be an Example object filled with random data, and `someString` will be set to `mySpecificValue`.

###### Extra

One important consideration when using generated data: You need to be sure that the code acts the same even when the data changes! Kotlinfixture generates different random values by default. To get some control you might want to set a [nullability strategy](https://github.com/appmattus/kotlinfixture/blob/main/fixture/configuration-options.adoc#overriding-nullability-with-nullabilitystrategy) and [optional strategy](https://github.com/appmattus/kotlinfixture/blob/main/fixture/configuration-options.adoc#overriding-the-use-of-default-values-with-optionalstrategy) since `null` and optional parameters often change code flow. You can make the generated data completely deterministic by [setting a seed](https://github.com/appmattus/kotlinfixture/blob/main/fixture/configuration-options.adoc#providing-a-seeded-random).

Found [Instancio](https://www.instancio.org/) as an alternative if you are using Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [Instancio](https://github.com/instancio/instancio/) a try (disclaimer: I'm the author of this library).

By default, it populates all fields with non-null values, non-blank Strings, and positive numbers.

```java
data class Example(
    val someInt: Int,
    val someString: String,
    val someObject: Any,
)

val result = Instancio.create(Example::class.java)

// Sample output
// Example(someInt=9737, someString=QXUIJKX, someObject=java.lang.Object@b3ca52e)
```

You can also override generated values. Check out the [user guide](https://www.instancio.org/user-guide/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but maybe this helps.

I would create a class like

```
public class YourClass{
int something = 0;
}
```

Then no arg constructor - this should construct a YourClass object with something = 0 in it.

Then constructor with (int something) - this should handle the case when the default value needs to be overwritten.

Comment: The OP specifically said they don't want the defaults to apply to production code, though. It should be mandatory constructor arguments in production

Comment: I see, youre right.

Answer (score 0):

My naive solution based on reflection:

usage:

```
fake<Book>().copy(name="hello")
```

code:

```
package com.cjy.yplusplus.util

inline fun <reified T : Any> fake() = Fakes.fakeImpl(T::class.java) as T

object Fakes {
    fun <T : Any> fakeImpl(clazz: Class<T>) = createFakeObject(clazz)

    private val INFOS = listOf(
        Info(listOf(Int::class.java, java.lang.Integer::class.java)) { 0 },
        Info(listOf(Long::class.java, java.lang.Long::class.java)) { 0L },
        Info(listOf(Double::class.java, java.lang.Double::class.java)) { 0.0 },
        Info(listOf(Float::class.java, java.lang.Float::class.java)) { 0.0f },
        Info(listOf(String::class.java, java.lang.String::class.java)) { "" },
        Info(listOf(List::class.java, MutableList::class.java, java.util.List::class.java)) { ArrayList<Any?>() },
        Info(listOf(Map::class.java, MutableMap::class.java, java.util.Map::class.java)) { HashMap<Any?, Any?>() },
    )

    private fun createFakeObject(type: Class<*>): Any {
        println("createFakeObject type=$type")

        // special check, notice it is "==" not "isAssignableFrom"
        if (type == Any::class.java || type == Object::class.java) {
            return Object()
        }

        return INFOS
            .firstOrNull { info -> info.classes.any { infoClazz -> infoClazz.isAssignableFrom(type) } }
            ?.defaultValue?.invoke()
            ?: createFakeObjectByConstructor(type)
    }

    private fun createFakeObjectByConstructor(clazz: Class<*>): Any {
        println("createFakeObjectByConstructor clazz=$clazz")
        val ctor = clazz.constructors.first()
        val args = ctor.parameterTypes.map { createFakeObject(it) }.toTypedArray()
        println("createFakeObjectByConstructor ctor=$ctor args=$args")
        return ctor.newInstance(*args)
    }

    private data class Info(
        val classes: List<Class<*>>,
        val defaultValue: () -> Any,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use IntelliJ IDEA you may define [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.3/using-live-templates.html) for this:
[image]

Now, in the context of a Kotlin variable creation (actually, any expression creation) you have a smart completion for "example" abbreviation:

[image]

Unfortunately, it can't be limited to the scope of Tests Files (this live template will be shown for all Kotlin code).